# How do you use cgo WITHOUT using make?

Tags: makefile, go

I use a custom build tool to compile go projects and I need a way to use cgo in my project.

The problem is that the cgo documentation only tells you how to use it with make.

What I really need to know is which generated files to process with which tools and in what order it needs to be done. I tried to read make.pkg in the go source dir but my best effort fails.

My test dll is very simple, a single function that returns 1 every time it is called and the go code to use this function is similarly simple.

The output from the console produced by a successful run of make on a cgo project would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output of running `make` on 32-bit Linux in directory [misc/cgo/life](http://golang.org/misc/cgo/life):

```
# gomake _obj/life.a
CGOPKGPATH= cgo --  life.go 
touch _obj/_cgo_run
8g  -o _go_.8  _obj/life.cgo1.go _obj/_cgo_gotypes.go
8c -FVw -I ${GOROOT}/pkg/linux_386 -I . -o "_cgo_defun.8" _obj/_cgo_defun.c
gcc -m32 -I . -g -fPIC -O2 -o _cgo_main.o -c   _obj/_cgo_main.c
gcc -m32 -g -fPIC -O2 -o c-life.o -c   c-life.c
gcc -m32 -I . -g -fPIC -O2 -o life.cgo2.o -c   _obj/life.cgo2.c
gcc -m32 -I . -g -fPIC -O2 -o _cgo_export.o -c   _obj/_cgo_export.c
gcc -m32 -g -fPIC -O2 -o _cgo1_.o _cgo_main.o c-life.o life.cgo2.o _cgo_export.o  
cgo -dynimport _cgo1_.o >_obj/_cgo_import.c_ && mv -f _obj/_cgo_import.c_ _obj/_cgo_import.c
8c -FVw -I . -o "_cgo_import.8" _obj/_cgo_import.c
rm -f _obj/life.a
gopack grc _obj/life.a _go_.8  _cgo_defun.8 _cgo_import.8 c-life.o  life.cgo2.o _cgo_export.o
```

The line `cgo -- life.go` creates the following files:

```
_obj/_cgo_.o
_obj/life.cgo1.go
_obj/life.cgo2.c
_obj/_cgo_gotypes.go
_obj/_cgo_defun.c
_obj/_cgo_main.c
_obj/_cgo_flags
_obj/_cgo_export.c
_cgo_export.h
```

Answer (score 1):

"*I use a custom build tool to compile go projects and I need a way to use cgo in my project.*"

... and this approach leads to problems. Using the standard way with a Makefile is simple, easy, proven, documented, etc.

I realize I'm not (directly) answering your question. Instead my "answer" is: I strongly suggest to use the standard way. Don't create problems for your self by choosing other, not directly supported options.

That said, I think there is a way to avoid the Makefiles, I just never been there, sorry. I'm usually lazy/short of time, so I use the simplest/fastest way to get things done. You might want to try the same ;-)

Comment: The make file does not work for me. It references all kinds of unix/linux specific commands that are not available on windows. I tried to modify the make files to work but I didn't have much luck.

Comment: I would like to add that the console output from running make on a cgo project would be invaluable. That at least would give me a huge boost in reverse engineering the steps needed

Comment: "The Go 1 release will include a new tool `go` that will replace both goinstall and make." from [Go 1 Preview](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1ny8uI-_BHrDCZv_zNBSthNKAMX_fR_0dc6epA6lztRE)